# Click Down/Up keys for scrolling inside ul element- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, element

I got a problem trying to make my own Autocomplete component in react..
I created a component which render the results and set max-height on their wrapper,
I used an onKeyDown event on the input element to track down/up key press. Right now I use it to mark the active item... but when the max-height I set is too small and there is a scroll in the side when the "active-item" go off the div's height limit the scroll doesn't go down with it... How can I fix it?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const Autocomplete = ({ options }) => {
  const [activeOption, setActiveOption] = useState(4)
  const [filteredOptions, setFilteredOptions] = useState([])
  const [showOptions, setShowOptions] = useState(false)
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowOptions(userInput)
    setFilteredOptions([
      ...options.filter(
        option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
      )
    ])
    setActiveOption(0)
  }, [userInput])

  const handleKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      if (activeOption === filteredOptions.length - 1) return
      setActiveOption(activeOption + 1)
    }
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      if (activeOption === 0) return
      setActiveOption(activeOption - 1)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="search">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search-box"
          value={userInput}
          onChange={e => setUserInput(e.target.value)}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        />
        <ul className="options">
          {showOptions &&
            filteredOptions.map((option, i) => (
              <li className={activeOption === i ? `option-active` : ``} key={i}>
                {option}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Autocomplete

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        options={[
          "Alligator",
          "Bask",
          "Crocodilian",
          "Death Roll",
          "Eggs",
          "Jaws",
          "Reptile",
          "Solitary",
          "Tail",
          "Wetlands"
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```css
.option-active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.options {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: overlay;
}
```

Here's a picture to explain better my problem:
when second item is active:
[image]

when the sixth is active:
[image]

As you can see the scroll stays the same and doesn't go down with the li element...
Thanks by heart!

Comment: Have you tried `setFocus` on the new selected element?

Comment: @RafaelMora I tried using a ref and then use ref.current.focus() but that did not work...

Comment: try: `container = $('MyElement').get(0);
container.scrollTop = (container.scrollHeight + container.offsetHeight);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could maintain an array of element refs, in order to call `scrollIntoView` method of that element, when active option changes.

Untested code:

```js
// Use a ref container (we won't use `current`)
const elmRefs = useRef()

// Instead we build a custom ref object in each key of the ref for each option
useEffect(() => {
  options.forEach(opt => elmRefs[opt] = {current: null} 
}, [options])

// Effect that scrolls active element when it changes
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  // This is what makes element visible
  elmRefs[options[activeOption]].current.scrollIntoView()
}, [options, activeOption])

// In the "render" section, connect each option to elmRefs
<li className={activeOption === i ? `option-active` : ``} ref={elmRefs[option]} key={i}>
  {option}
</li>
```

Let me know what you think!

Edit:

If the elmRefs need to be initialized imediately, you could do:

```js
// Outside component
const initRefs = options => Object.fromEntries(options.map(o => [o, {current: null}]))

// Then in the component, replace useRef by:
const elmRefs = useRef(initRef(options))
```

And replace `elmRefs` by `elmRefs.current` in the rest of the code...